# Length of a common side of 2 inscribed triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

I have 2 scalene triangle (with 1 side common) inscribed in a circle.
Triangle 1: One side has length = 10 and other x
Triangle 2: One side has length = 12 and other x
I need to find the length of the common side x. Here's how it looks:
Any hint or a formula I can use?
[image]

Comment: Why did you post the same question twice?

Comment: I saw the status of the first was closed and was not satisfactory

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Join all other chords and by *angles in the same segment*, you'll see the two adjacent chords are equal (i.e. the two adjacent sides at the bottom of the cyclic quadrilateral).  Now equating the equal sides by cosine law:

$$10^2+x^2-2(10)x\cos 30^{\circ}=12^2+x^2-2(12)x\cos 30^{\circ}$$

Can you proceed?

Comment: Thx.. It does :-)